# Creating a horizontal separator in a vertical UIStackView

Tags: xamarin.ios, uistackview

I have a vertical stack view that contains a number of horizontal stack views. How can I create a 1px separator line between the horizontal stackviews?

Comment: judging by the lack of response I am assuming it cant be done.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Separator View:

```
class SeparatorView: UIView {

    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        setUp()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setUp()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func setUp() {
        backgroundColor = .gray
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height:0.5)
    }
}
```

And add it to your StackView in between the horizontal views:

```
stackView.addArrangedSubview(horizontalView)
stackView.addArrangedSubview(SeparatorView())
```

This will create a small gray line that separates the views.

Comment: Or even better instead of setting a height of `0.5` set it to 1px properly `1 / UIScreen.main.scale`

Answer (score 0):

just add in a UIView with a 1-2px width and the same height as each of the horizontal stack views in between the two middle most controls in the horizontal stack view. Assuming that there is no top or bottom spacing it would give the impression of a vertical line without breaks, or if you don't mind breaks in the vertical line then don't worry about removing top or bottom spacing.

OR

You could leverage the fact that UIStackView can take subviews, and just work out the centre x, and with a y of 0, add in a 2px wide UIView as a subview of the UIStackView.

Something like:

```
        UIStackView sv = new UIStackView();
        UIView ViewLine = new UIView();
        ViewLine.Frame = new CGRect(CentreX, 0 , 2f , heightofstackview );
        sv.AddSubview();
```